# Google Cloud postgres instance not able to connect to spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

**I am using postgresSQL instance on google cloud platform in spring boot app with spring data JPA.**

But i am not able to connect to postgresSQL instance at the time of deployment.
I am not really sure on what dependency is required for this and what is the application properties configuration.

here is the code.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://google/postgres?cloudSqlInstance=<instance-name>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

pom.xml

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

app.yml for deployment on flex environment:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
service: payment2
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <instance-name>
```

Thanks in advance.Please help!!!